# How to trigger AWS CodeDeploy application from another deployment succeeds trigger event

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-code-deploy

We would like to set up a separate EC2 staging server that mirrors our set up in our AWS EC2 production setup.  We have a Code Deploy application that is set up to copy our artifacts to the EC2 instances in our production environment.  I see that in the Code Deploy application I can create a trigger that fires when a certain deployment event occurs.  What I can't find clear direction on is how to set up something, somewhere to listen for that SNS topic and then kick off another Code Deploy application which would copy the same artifacts to a staging server EC2 instance.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

CodeDeploy [sends events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-cloudwatch-events.html) to AWS EventBridge. You can create an EventBridge rule that triggers on a `SUCCESS` event from your first CodeDeploy, and have that trigger another CodeDeploy. Alternatively, you can have CodeDeploy [send events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/monitoring-sns-event-notifications-create-trigger.html) directly to an SNS topic.

You can then use the event to trigger a new CodeDeploy run [via CodePipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codeartifact/latest/ug/configure-service-events-codepipeline.html).